# How to disable user accounts on firebase authentication automatically?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

I am currently working on an android application which uses Google Firebase as the back end server.

One function I want to implement is disabling user accounts as they register through the application but I don't know how to do it.

Does anyone know how to implement this into the android code itself?

Comment: Authentication is nothing more than proving that you are you. There is no way to disable that in Firebase Authentication. The common requirement is that new users can't access specific data, which you do on your data access layer. For example: for the Firebase Database, you can easily implement a whitelist in security rules. Also see this discussion on the firebase-talk group: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/yH8PMmz4xYA

Answer (score 39):

There's no method to disable a user account from the Android client SDK.

You have to use Firebase Admin SDK for this.

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
    disabled: true
});
```

Guide link: [Firebase Admin - Update a user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/manage-users#update_a_user)

**EDIT: Thanks @FrankvanPuffelen**

You can also trigger this function when a Firebase user is created on Firebase Cloud Function.

[read more here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation)

Comment: If you trigger this automatically from a Cloud Function when the user is created, you'll have a pretty decent flow. See https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events#trigger_a_function_on_user_creation

Comment: ah yes, I forgot that we have Cloud Function already. thanks @FrankvanPuffelen. I will update my answer :)

Comment: I tried this with a firebase function, its takes too long to trigger so the recently created user is already automatically logged in by the time it is disabled :-(, causing the admin user to logout

Comment: The time can vary and the login part of the register user function will fail sometimes but not all the time.  I needed to add a delay until I find a better solution as this will charge you for 5s cloud function use each time.

Comment: export const disableNewUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate((user) => {
  // TODO: Timeout is not ideal.  Need to find a better solution.
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      return admin.auth().updateUser(user.uid, {
        disabled: true
      }).then(resolve, reject)
    }, 5000);
  });
});