# Is there some way in firebase firestore to block the user from signing in with the same email or gmail account?

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm curious if it's possible in firestore to block the user's gmail or email account and prevent that user from signing in or registering again

Answer (score 0):

If you go to authentication and disable that user, they will not be able to sign in or register

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the user to prevent further access. You can't disable user using client SDK(react in your case), must use firebase admin API to do this. Something like this:

```
admin.auth().updateUser(uid, {
    disabled: true
});
```

For more info:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/43141780/8087468

Comment: I actually plan to add something like a 'block' button in which the admin can block that user from using his or her gmail or email account. I'll need to install the firebase admin SDK then

Comment: You can use server or firebase functions between client and that function, the flow should be like this that you/Admin will click on the block button it would send the request to server or firebase function which would eventually run this piece of code.